# Name of pawn struture in B42 Sicilian defense

Tags: opening, sicilian-defense, positional-play, pawn-structure

I like positional games, and the Sicilian defence is very dynamic, however the B42 Sicilian defence is quite positional, but the pawn structure has some weaknesses. I would like to learn more about the B42 pawn structure and the name, or where to seek more information on the B42 Sicilian pawn structure.

Comment: Why don't you describe this Sicilian Pawn structure with a diagram? I was familiar with Chess Informant / Openings Encyclopedia terminology some 30 years ago, but nowadays I hardly remember it. Not everyone knows it by heart.

Comment: As a start, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pawn_structure#Sicilian_%E2%80%93_Scheveningen It does not mention B42 (Kan Sicilian) explicitly, but most everything should apply.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Johan Hellsten-Play the Kan](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14nKd6uXbmUT2VEYeiQ597S7Jou1GzqXf), there are six structures found in the Kan.

1. Classical Sicilian Structure
2. Hedgehog Structure
3. Enhanced Hedgehog Structure
4. Maroczy Bind
5. Aggressive Maroczy Bind
6. Classical Maroczy Bind